# R: create new column with for-Loops

Tags: r, dplyr

I have large dataframe like this

```
 df <- data.frame(min =seq(1,90, by=1), event=sample(LETTERS,90,replace=TRUE))
```

And I would like to create new column (segment) to identify and name segments between specific values.

For example, first segment should start from the beginning of dataframe until event "A". Second segment should start after "A" and continue until next event "A". And last segment should start from the last "A" until end of dataframe.

It's better to show desired output

| min | event | segment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | 1-5 |
| 2 | D | 1-5 |
| 3 | D | 1-5 |
| 4 | E | 1-5 |
| 5 | A | 1-5 |
| 6 | E | 6-10 |
| 7 | G | 6-10 |
| 8 | G | 6-10 |
| 9 | G | 6-10 |
| 10 | A | 6-10 |
| 11 | F | 11-12 |
| 12 | G | 11-12 |

I know that I should to use for-Loops but a bit confused how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for explicit loops. Some simple data manipulation within `dplyr` should do the trick:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(min = 1:12, 
                 event = c("C", "D", "D", "E", "A", 
                           "E", "G", "G", "G", "A", "F", "G"))

df %>%
  mutate(cluster = lag(cumsum(event == "A"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(segment = paste(first(min), last(min), sep = "-"), .by = "cluster") %>%
  select(-cluster)
#>    min event segment
#> 1    1     C     1-5
#> 2    2     D     1-5
#> 3    3     D     1-5
#> 4    4     E     1-5
#> 5    5     A     1-5
#> 6    6     E    6-10
#> 7    7     G    6-10
#> 8    8     G    6-10
#> 9    9     G    6-10
#> 10  10     A    6-10
#> 11  11     F   11-12
#> 12  12     G   11-12
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution.
Create a logical inddexon the beginning of each segment. `tapply` grouping by that index (with a standard `cumsum` trick) will get thlengths of the segments. Then, determine the start and end of each segment, paste them together and replicate those values to get the wanted vector.

```r
set.seed(2023)
df <- data.frame(min =seq(1,90, by=1), event=sample(LETTERS,90,replace=TRUE))

i_A <- df$event == "A"
n <- with(df, tapply(event, cumsum(i_A), length))
if(!i_A[nrow(df)]) i_A[nrow(df)] <- TRUE
end <- which(i_A)
start <- c(0L, end[-length(end)]) + 1L
df$segment <- rep(paste(start, end, sep = "-"), n)
head(df)
#>   min event segment
#> 1   1     U    1-11
#> 2   2     P    1-11
#> 3   3     O    1-11
#> 4   4     I    1-11
#> 5   5     H    1-11
#> 6   6     S    1-11
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>